# Jquery ajax post create a second form on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this form:

```
<form id='form'>
  Begin time<input id="begintime" type="text" name="begintime"><br>
  End time<input id="endtime" type="text" name="endtime"><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

on my website it looks like this:

[image]

the thing is that I don't want the web page to refresh. so I made this ajax post:

```
      $(function () {

    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var begin = $("#begintime").val();
      var end = $("#endtime").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '',
        data: {begin: begin, end: end},
        success: function (result) {
            $( result ).appendTo('p');
        }
      });

    });

    });
```

But every time is click on submit this happens:

[image]

also I use this to get the data:

```
        <p>
<?php 
$begin = $_POST['begin'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
?>
</p>
```

I have tried this:

```
   $('p').empty();
```

I put tihs inside of ajax code this is the result is the same. What am I doing wrong? please help. and thank you.

Comment: You don't need to fully submit the form with an XHR request.  Change your input for submit to a standard button tag, and remap the listener for a click event.  Then you can fire off your ajax request and stop the form from submitting, which will make the page not reload and get full of input tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below instead. It will clear everything inside the p tag and append the form to i

```
success: function (result) {
    $('p').html(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just change the HTML, not append it like so

```
...
success: function (result) {
    $('p').html(result);
}
...
```